# Merging meshes in the hierarchy

Tags: mesh

In the hierarchy, I have two meshes called "Cube" that I'd like to merge together:

[image: Cube meshes]

Most answers that I've found online say to <kbd>Shift</kbd> select both and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> to merge them. However, weirdly that doesn't work in my case. If I select both the green triangles with dots and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>, nothing happens. If I select both of the yellow triangles and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>, nothing happens. If I select all four of these and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>, nothing happens. In all of these situations it's as if I wasn't pressing <kbd>J</kbd> at all, nothing changes on screen.

Is there something weird about my situation that would cause <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> to not work?

It's especially frustrating that Blender 2.8 doesn't give any errors or any reason why it's not joining the meshes as I wish it to.

Comment: It works in the 3D view! It's weird that nobody previously mentioned you have to use the 3D view or can't use the hierarchy or something.

Comment: I'm not into 2.8 but at a guess, if you'd firstly pressed the greenies and CTL-J'd those, then tried the same with the Orange ones, you might have joined or linked them in edit mode and upset the process. When you click on a green icon in earlier versions you're automatically switched to Edit mode.  Make sure there's no link between them or load in an earlier save, then Just select the orange icons on their own with shift.  Do a CTL-J, but in the 3D window.

Comment: Are you saying that you have to be in a particular mode to merge meshes?

Comment: As far as I'm aware that is the case, yes.  Be in Object mode and have your cursor in the 3D window when you do the CTL-J.  I'm talking Vers 2.77.  Haven't seen anything that mentions 2.8 is any different to date.  Selecting both objects in the 3D window is probably easier and less confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per @Edgel3D's advice and my own experimentation, it seems that it's impossible to merge meshes in the hierarchy. All merging must be done in Object Mode in the 3D view, or else nothing will happen.

Hopefully this helps someone else who had the same problem and is wondering why <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> isn't working.